# Custom Font in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, typeface

I am currently trying to implement a custom font on one of my `fragments`. I've tried using this code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    mRecyclerView =rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    id = rootView.findViewById(R.id.count);
    catename = rootView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    Typeface sans = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/IRANSans.ttf");
    catename.setTypeface(sans);

   // other code
    return rootView;
}
```

The font does not change and the output remains the default type. I have already created an `assets` folder in the main project folder, with a "fonts" sub-folder which contains the file **"IRANSans.TTF"**.

---

But it force closes at this statement `txt.setTypeface(font)`:

Does anyone know to fix this problem? Below is the logcat:

---

```
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5753)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
   at aracode.ir.login.fragments.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:69)
```

Comment: Here textview is null. So try this `catename = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.title);`

Comment: share your xml file

Comment: try this you do not need write any code https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to typecast TextView properly:-

```
catename =(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.title);

Typeface sans = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/IRANSans.ttf");
catename.setTypeface(sans);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a `NullPointerException` and not a Type Casting error, then you need to check your `fragment_home.xml`, and make sure there's a TextView with `android:id="@+id/title"`